# Advantage of using object initializer over constructor function for Prototype Inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Are there any advantages to using object initializer vs constructor function?  I see with constructor function you create an instance with the new keyword while with an object initializer it just creates an instance for you when you try to use it.

Is it purely/literally just a matter of style only or are there some hidden benefits or differences of using one vs. the other that people should be aware of when it comes to wanting to do dependency injection through prototype inheritance and setting the values as you build the prototype chain?

for example if I want to set prototypes and values on the prototype for an object initializer instance, is the constructor and prototype accessed and set the same way as you would with a NEW constructor function object?  Do they equate to representing an object no matter what and how you start setting their prototypes really is no different after you have the new object?

Are most people creating objects for purpose of setting prototypes using constructor functions or object literals these days?

I have node 4.0 so I have ES6 at my disposal but would like to know about the plain object literal vs. constructor function techniques first.  If you have an es6 version that makes it easier fine, feel free to contribute your input on that too.

FYI I'm also coding in node.js if this even has any relevance or has any effect on the conversation..

Comment: Did [none of these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+object+literal+vs+constructor) give you a satisfying answer? If not, why not? What else would you like to know?

Comment: This might be interesting for you then: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes

Comment: I would say this is not really an opinion-based question because it doesn't simply which is preferred, but it asks about the advantages and disadvantages of each method which is based of facts. But this question has been asked before many times.

Comment: thanks a lot for the link Felix, that one is great